# Reflection methods fail when types are in other assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, reference

I'm making a little tool to analyze code dependencies recursively. I found a problem: if I try to get a member of a class whose signature contains a reference to another dll the method fails. For example, if I have a simple class in Main.exe

```
public class MainClass  {
    public MainClass () {
        foo();
    }

    public ContainedClass GetPublicClass () {
        return new ContainedClass ();
    }

}
```

and `ContainedClass` is defined in other file refers.dll, when I try the following code it throw a `FileNotFoundException`  in `met3.ReturnType()` method cause .net not find refers.dll.

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\dir\Main.exe");
Type typ =  assem.GetType ("MultipleReference.MainClass");
MethodInfo met3 = typ.GetMethod ("GetPublicClass");
met3.ReturnType.ToString ();
```

Is there any way to indicate where to search the dll?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) instead of [LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) because it will also resolve and load dependent assemblies. Quoting the documentation:

> Use the LoadFile method to load and
>   examine assemblies that have the same
>   identity, but are located in different
>   paths. LoadFile does not load files
>   into the LoadFrom context, and does
>   not resolve dependencies using the
>   load path, as the LoadFrom method
>   does. LoadFile is useful in this
>   limited scenario because LoadFrom
>   cannot be used to load assemblies that
>   have the same identities but different
>   paths; it will load only the first
>   such assembly.

Comment: Just an addition, you can manually handle this using the AssemblyResolve handler at the AppDomain level if for some reason you would like to... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx